# Create a Tab (call it MNOP) with a layout that contains textboxes that take data(numbers).

Tags: tabs, textbox, pyqt, qwidget, qlabel

How do I create a tab in a PyQT UI that has a layout that contains the following, example.

tab name-MNOP

Layout has.

- a1: textbox that can input data (numbers)
- a2: textbox hat can input data
- a3: textbox that can input data
- a4: textbox that can input data

the data input will be stored in the db and used to create bar-graphs. right now I need to create the tab and textboxes.

right now, I am working with the following-incomplete but don't know how to proceed.

```
class RPBDlg(QDialog):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(RPBDlg, self).__init__(parent) 
    self.newcounter =0 


    grid = QGridLayout()  
    label = QLabel() 
    label.setText("<B>Plan Title:</B>") 
    self.titleEdit = QLineEdit() 


    grid.addWidget(label,0,0,1,1) 
    grid.addWidget(self.titleEdit,0,1,1,1)
    label2 = QLabel("<B>Type of Plan</B>") 
    self.typeEdit = QComboBox() 
    self.typeEdit.addItems(["STI","LTI","STI and LTI"])  

    grid.addWidget(label2,1,0,1,1) 
    grid.addWidget(self.typeEdit,1,1,1,1)
    self.bonusPool = QCheckBox("Bonus Pool") 
    grid.addWidget(self.bonusPool,1,4,1,1) 
    label3 = QLabel("<B>Sub-Type of Plan<B>") 
    self.subTypeEdit = QComboBox() 
    self.subTypeEdit.addItems(["Regular","Profit Sharing","Multiplier Based"]) 
    grid.addWidget(label3,1,2,1,1)
    grid.addWidget(self.subTypeEdit,1,3,1,1)
    self.label4 = QLabel("<B>Are individual awards determined <br>through a performance formula?")
    self.bonusPoolAdditional = QComboBox() 
    self.bonusPoolAdditional.addItems(["Yes - separate formula for individual awards","Yes - individual awards are proportional to bonus pool", "No - individual awards are discretionary","No - individual awards determined through negative discretion"])
    grid.addWidget(self.label4,3,0,1,1) 
    grid.addWidget(self.bonusPoolAdditional,3,1,1,2)
```

Imports are present. This code is part of a much larger code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use tabs in your UI you should create a `QTabWidget`. The basic steps for working with it are:

- create a `QTabWidget`.
- Create a QWidget with no parent for each of the pages in the tab dialog.
  for them.
- Insert child widgets into the page widget, using layouts to position them as normal.
- Call addTab() or insertTab() to put the page widgets into the tab widget, giving each tab a suitable label with an optional keyboard shortcut.

You can find detailed information in the [documentation page](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtabwidget.html) of the widget.

Comment: Thanks, Vicent. But I am absolutely new to PyQt and so have a very poor undersanding of its logic. I have put up another question here describing the problem (but no code) - you can look it up by clicking on my username. Thanks again :) Further, I checked the existing code and there is a "QTabWidget" reference there, but from my POV, it is in the wrong place but the thing works. So, my logic must be screwed.